# how to check file type by using (def) function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, user-defined-types

```
def is_image(fname):
    for files in files_in_dir('./W06'):
        if files[-3] =='jpg':
            return True
        return False
x = is_image('.jpg')
print(x)
```

I wonder what did i do wrong in this part when i run the code it always says false, it suppose to say true if last 3 letter is jpg. please help me im new to python

Comment: Try `files[-3:]`

Comment: Or more readably, `if files.endswith('.jpg')`

Comment: You're not using `fname` in your function.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious error is that you checked the index `-3` and not the slice `-3:`. Note the difference:

```
>>> "abc.def"[-3]
'd'
>>> "abc.def"[-3:]
'def'
>>>
```

Apart from this, the overall method seems a bit awkward. You have `fname` as a parameter but don't actually use it. You're also testing for the presence of any file in a directory with that extension. Further, if you want to test the presence of a predicate in a list, you can use the `any` method.

I'd recommend something like this:

```
def dir_contains_ext(dir, ext):
    return any(
        files.endswith(ext)
        for file in files_in_dir(dir)
    )


dir_contains_ext('./W06', '.jpg')
```